# Ploting a matrix using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, matrix, ggplot2

I want to plot using `ggplot2` the distribution of 5 variables corresponding to a matrix's column names

```
a <- matrix(runif(1:25),ncol=5,nrow=1)
colnames(a) <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
rownames(a) <- c("count")
```

I tried:

```
ggplot(data=melt(a),aes(x=colnames(a),y=a[,1]))+ geom_point()
```

However, this gives a result as if all columns had the same y value

Note: i'm using the `reshape` package for the `melt()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All columns look like they have the same y-value because you are only specifying 1 number in the `y=` statement. You are saying `y=a[,1]` which if you type `a[,1]` into your command window you will find is `0.556` (the number that everything is appearing at). I think this is what you want:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

a_melt<- melt(a)
ggplot(data=a_melt,aes(x=unique(Var2),y=value))+ geom_point()
```

[image]

Note that I saved a new dataset called `a_melt` so that things were easier to reference. Also since the data was melted,it is cleaner if we define our x-values to be the `Var2` column of `a_melt`rather than the columns of `a`.

Comment: I get Error in unique(Var2) : object 'Var2' not found. From where do Var2 and value come from ?

Comment: The code works for me. Did you run it using the original data you posted?